# Cute Handwriting in Korean?

Tags: hangul

I have seen different fonts in Korean. Some are considered cuter than others. What makes them be perceived as cute? Are there some examples of cute handwriting? (in your opinion)

Also, is it acceptable to write a 'ㅎ' with just one horizontal line above the 'ㅇ'?

Comment: I like the question, but I think it should be closed as 'cute' is a matter of opinion. Sorry.

Comment: @Taladris I agree that "what *is* cute" is of course a matter of opinion... my reading of this question was more that it asks *"what is considered/perceived as" cute*, which is something that would ultimately have some basis in statistics.

Comment: I think that there can be a general definition of what is perceived as cute especially with handwriting. You can look at something and say that it is cute, not for you personally but for others.
(And, this isn't a factual question, it is asking for opinion. Without knowing others' opinion, it is sometimes hard to come to a decision/answer.)

Comment: it is generally the etiquette in stack exchange websites to not ask opinion based questions

Comment: Historically, doesn't language change with how people use it? At some point, language questions can't be expected to be entirely void of opinion.

Comment: There used to be a ㆆ (called 여린히읗 _yeorinhieut_ or 된 이응 _doen-ieung_), probably with a glottal stop as its phonetic value, and different to ㅎ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Hangul is still not very good. As a learner, I find I have difficulty with

- Arranging the Jamo into blocks of consistent size
- Tightly arranging blocks with two vowels, like '와' or '귀'

accordingly, many 'cute' fonts deliberately exhibit the same 'problems'.

from http://blog.daum.net/dayeon3189/56,

This font shows mismatched character block sizes:

[image: rom http://blog.daum.net/dayeon3189/56]

You can see that the three-character blocks are much bigger than the two-character blocks.

In this example, you can see the '퀴' is not tightly arranged:

[image]

I make these 'mistakes' all the time; accordingly, people often see my writing as 'cute'!

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that "cute" is a bit subjective, but the "cute" fonts I've seen are generally somewhere between a "proper/formal" font, and the handwriting of a child, where you find the imbalances in spacing and size, which are common to children or people just learning to write.

In addition, one could associate thick, rounded strokes with rounded ends and lack of serifs in that colored font:

[image]

versus one that doesn't have those qualities:

[image]

The fonts just replicate certain aspects of that imbalance while still maintaining legibility.

> Also, is it acceptable to write a 'ㅎ' with just one horizontal line above the 'ㅇ'?

No, that would be like writing a K without the one of the lines.  It wouldn't be considered a letter.  :)

Answer (score 1):

What makes Korean hand writing look cute?

When I was in school one of my classmate's handwriting was cute, but hard to read. My guess is, it depends on the person who is writing, someone who has good handwriting and knows cuteness maybe they can write cute Korean.

If you are talking about font in computer take a look link below.

They have good font + high readability compare to normal Korean font.
http://hangeul.naver.com/2016/nanum

> Q> Also, is it acceptable to write a 'ㅎ' with just one horizontal line
>   above the 'ㅇ'?

```
A> Not really. It will not be 'ㅎ' or 'ㅇ' in modern notation.
  (but long time ago they put dot above 'ㅇ')
```